# What statistical tests would be effective for this design?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, experiment-design, likert

Here the basics: 
Group 1 is the control group, they are given a specific website to use. 
Group 2 is the experimental group, they are given a similar website, with adjusted hypertext properties.

After they complete the required actions, they are asked to complete a survey, (Likert Scale) which attempts to measure their feeling on the security and convenience of the website.

This is the condensed version of the question. 
Just want to check.

The IV: Hypertext 
The DV: Security and Convenience (Measured through Likert Scale)

But which statistical tests in SPSS can I use to indicate a significant difference in the control and experimental group? And added advice would also be great.

New to stats, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Classic two-sample (a.k.a. independent samples) t-test would be an appropriate choice. It is common to regard a Likert scale as a continuous measure.

Possible extensions: you could form a latent factor from your security measure to theoretically purge it from measurement error. This would be a structural equation model in which you specify a latent factor comprised of the items in your security measurement and then use the grouping variable as a predictor of this latent factor.

You may consider some "robust" tests of group mean differences, if you suspect that the mean may not be the best possible measure of central tendency (e.g., due to outliers, small sample sizes, highly non-normal outcome variable). See e.g., tests of trimmed means, medians. Rand Wilcox did a lot of work on this, but to my knowledge this is not implemented in SPSS.

Comment: Thanks, that makes total sense. Will definitely have a look at 'tests of trimmed means, medians' etc. The sample will be quite small, so describing the statistical tests with that in mind is probably important. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

1) If the same website user will have to scale the two sites based on their security and convenience, you will have to use a paired t-test hoping that all other assumptions such as normality or large sample size and equal variances are made.
2) For the same assumptions as above in place, if the user that visit the sites are different the a two sample t-test is recommended.

Now if those assumptions fail, us a non-parametric version of these test pair-non parametric and two sample non-parametric (All are rank test). In SPSS you will find these tests. These are standard tests that are thought in all first lessons of a statistical course.